# How to convert a string to DateTime in a TextBox of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```cs
protected void grvHerstellingen_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = grvHerstellingen.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int herstellingLijstIndex = row.DataItemIndex;
    int klantid = (int)grvHerstellingen.DataKeys[herstellingLijstIndex].Value;

    int nieuweToestelid = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]);
    string nieuweDatumbinnen = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]); 
    string nieuweDatumklaar = ((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]);
    int nieuweKostprijs = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox) row.Cells[4].Controls[0]);

    _c.UpdateHerstelling(nieuweDatumbinnen, nieuweKostprijs, nieuweDatumklaar, nieuweToestelid, klantid);

    grvHerstellingen.EditIndex = -1;
    grvHerstellingen.DataSource = _c.GetAlleKlanten();
    grvHerstellingen.DataBind();
}
```

Hi there, I am trying to convert the `nieuweDatumbinnen` and `nieuweDatumklaar` to DateTime im my Textbox, but I haven't found anything yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like this is in Dutch? You'll probably find you get a better response, if it was in English

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Ill ask it once again.